# Need applescript to get total duration of videos in selected folder

Tags: video, applescript, directory, duration

i actually have applescript in which prompt is asking for folder to get total duration of videos in that folder, but instead of that i want to work this applescript as "Service" by just right clicking that folder and selecting my service i get duration of all videos in that folder. In that case i know how to make service from script. So please help me friends.

```css
-- time the following operation:
--set start_time to (time of (current date)) -- start timing

set this_folder to (choose folder with prompt "Pick the folder containing the video files to process:") as string

set video_ext_list to {"3g2", "3gp", "3gp2", "3gpp", "3mm", "60d", "aep", "ajp", "amv", "asf", "asx", "avb", "avi", "avs", "bik", "bix", "box", "byu", "cvc", "dce", "dif", "dir", "divx", "dv", "dvr-ms", "dxr", "eye", "fcp", "flc", "fli", "flv", "flx", "gl", "grasp", "gvi", "gvp", "ifo", "imovieproject", "ivf", "ivs", "izz", "izzy", "lsf", "lsx", "m1v", "m2v", "m4e", "m4u", "m4v", "mjp", "mkv", "moov", "mov", "movie", "mp4", "mpe", "mpeg", "mpg", "mpv2", "msh", "mswmm", "mvb", "mvc", "nvc", "ogm", "omf", "prproj", "prx", "qt", "qtch", "rm", "rmvb", "rp", "rts", "sbk", "scm", "smil", "smv", "spl", "srt", "ssm", "svi", "swf", "swi", "tivo", "ts", "vdo", "vf", "vfw", "vid", "viewlet", "viv", "vivo", "vob", "vro", "wm", "wmd", "wmv", "wmx", "wvx", "yuv"}


tell application "Finder"
 set these_files to ((files of folder this_folder whose name extension is in video_ext_list) as alias list)
end tell

set filesCount to count of these_files

set total_duration_of_files_in_seconds to ""
set files_with_no_duration to 0

repeat with i from 1 to filesCount
 set this_file to (item i of my these_files)
 set this_info to info for this_file
 if visible of this_info is true and alias of this_info is false then
  -- insert actions here for: this_file
  set this_file_duration_in_seconds to do shell script "mdls -name kMDItemDurationSeconds -raw -nullMarker 0 " & quoted form of POSIX path of this_file
  if this_file_duration_in_seconds is not 0 then
   set total_duration_of_files_in_seconds to total_duration_of_files_in_seconds + this_file_duration_in_seconds
  else
   set files_with_no_duration to files_with_no_duration + 1
  end if
 end if
end repeat

set total_duration_in_hms to do shell script " echo " & total_duration_of_files_in_seconds & " | awk '{printf \"%03d:%02d:%02d\",$0/3600,$0%3600/60,$0%60}'"

(*
set end_time to (time of (current date)) -- stop timing.
set elapsed_time to end_time - start_time

log "2. elapsed_time is is " & elapsed_time & " seconds."
*)

display dialog "Files processed : " & (count of these_files) & return & "Files without duration : " & files_with_no_duration & return & "Total duration of " & (count of these_files) - files_with_no_duration & " files in h:m:s : " & total_duration_in_hms with title "Length of all videos in a folder" buttons {"OK"} default button 1
```

Comment: Would it be possible to have this as a service when right-clicking on a folder or right clicking on selected media files (without the folder prompt)?

Answer (score 2):

- Launch Automator
- Click Button `New Document` or press <kbd>⌘N</kbd>
- Select `Service` and click `Choose`
- In the area above the canvas to drag actions into make these settings:[image]
- In the search field type <kbd>run ap</kbd>
- Drag a `Run AppleScript` action into the canvas
- Replace the entire code with

  ```
  on run {input, parameters}
      set sourceFolder to item 1 of input
      set video_ext_list to {"3g2", "3gp", "3gp2", "3gpp", "3mm", "60d", "aep", "ajp", "amv", "asf", "asx", "avb", "avi", "avs", "bik", "bix", "box", "byu", "cvc", "dce", "dif", "dir", "divx", "dv", "dvr-ms", "dxr", "eye", "fcp", "flc", "fli", "flv", "flx", "gl", "grasp", "gvi", "gvp", "ifo", "imovieproject", "ivf", "ivs", "izz", "izzy", "lsf", "lsx", "m1v", "m2v", "m4e", "m4u", "m4v", "mjp", "mkv", "moov", "mov", "movie", "mp4", "mpe", "mpeg", "mpg", "mpv2", "msh", "mswmm", "mvb", "mvc", "nvc", "ogm", "omf", "prproj", "prx", "qt", "qtch", "rm", "rmvb", "rp", "rts", "sbk", "scm", "smil", "smv", "spl", "srt", "ssm", "svi", "swf", "swi", "tivo", "ts", "vdo", "vf", "vfw", "vid", "viewlet", "viv", "vivo", "vob", "vro", "wm", "wmd", "wmv", "wmx", "wvx", "yuv"}


      tell application "Finder"
          set these_files to ((files of sourceFolder whose name extension is in video_ext_list) as alias list)
      end tell

      set filesCount to count of these_files

      set total_duration_of_files_in_seconds to ""
      set files_with_no_duration to 0

      repeat with i from 1 to filesCount
          set this_file to (item i of my these_files)
          set this_info to info for this_file
          if visible of this_info is true and alias of this_info is false then
              -- insert actions here for: this_file
              set this_file_duration_in_seconds to do shell script "mdls -name kMDItemDurationSeconds -raw -nullMarker 0 " & quoted form of POSIX path of this_file
              if this_file_duration_in_seconds is not "0" then
                  set total_duration_of_files_in_seconds to total_duration_of_files_in_seconds + this_file_duration_in_seconds
              else
                  set files_with_no_duration to files_with_no_duration + 1
              end if
          end if
      end repeat

      set total_duration_in_hms to do shell script " echo " & total_duration_of_files_in_seconds & " | awk '{printf \"%03d:%02d:%02d\",$0/3600,$0%3600/60,$0%60}'"

      (*
      set end_time to (time of (current date)) -- stop timing.
      set elapsed_time to end_time - start_time

      log "2. elapsed_time is is " & elapsed_time & " seconds."
      *)

      display dialog "Files processed : " & (count of these_files) & return & "Files without duration : " & files_with_no_duration & return & "Total duration of " & (count of these_files) - files_with_no_duration & " files in h:m:s : " & total_duration_in_hms with title "Length of all videos in a folder" buttons {"OK"} default button 1


      return input
  end run
  ```
- Save the Service
- In Finder select a folder and run the service from the contextual menu

---

Note: You have to check for string `"0"` not integer `0` in

```
if this_file_duration_in_seconds is not "0" then
```

because the shell script returns always strings and `is not 0` will always evaluate to `true`

Comment: To your "Note:"... Since it's normal to think of the _value_ in _seconds_ to be an `integer` and therefore the naming of the `this_file_duration_in_seconds` _variable_ would normally imply it's an `integer`, then I'd do just that and make it an `integer`, so `if this_file_duration_in_seconds is not 0 then` does not need have quotes around the _zero_, and use `set this_file_duration_in_seconds to (do shell script "mdls -name kMDItemDurationSeconds -raw -nullMarker 0 " & quoted form of POSIX path of this_file) as integer` for the `do shell script` _command_.

Comment: sourceFolder not defined

Comment: @EmmanuelGoldstein  `sourceFolder` **is** defined right after the `on run` line.

Comment: Thanks. It returns no errors, but the computed duration is always zero for some reason. I tried with different video files whose extensions are listed.